# implement two select in my view page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

My form have two select in my view page like this

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <p>Main</p>
                <div class="top5">
                  <select name="main" id="mainClass_select" class="form-control">
                    <option value="-1">All</option>
                    <% t(:main_skill_category).each_with_index do |main_one, index| %>
                    <% if index == @main_skill_id %>
                    <option value="<%= index %>" selected><%= main_one['name'] %></option>
                    <% else %>
                    <option value="<%= index %>"><%= main_one['name'] %></option>
                    <% end %>
                    <% end %>
                  </select>
                </div>   
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <p>子類別</p>
                <div class="top5">
                  <select name="sub" id="subClass_select2" class="form-control" >
                    <option value="-1">All</option>
                    <% t(:sub_skill_category)[@main_skill_id].each_with_index do |sub_one, index| %>
                    <% if index == @sub_skill_id %>
                    <option value="<%= index %>" selected><%= sub_one['name'] %></option>
                    <% else %>
                    <option value="<%= index %>"><%= sub_one['name'] %></option>
                    <% end %>
                    <% end %>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I hope after user select main select, the sub select will change the option.
(I have a yml files in my locales. example the English version: )

```
main_skill_category: [
{name: "IT、Software"},
{name: "Engineering、Science"},
{name: "Design、Creativity"},
{name: "Business、Marketing "},
{name: "General Affairs、Customer Services"},
{name: "Business、Accounting、Legal"},
{name: "Writing、Translation"},
{name: "Professional Advisory"}
]

sub_skill_category: [
[
  {name: "Programming", title: ""},
  {name: "Program test / debug", title: ""},
  {name: "E-commerce platform", title: ""},
  {name: "Web development", title: ""},
  {name: "Web planning", title: ""},
  {name: "Web test", title: ""},
  {name: "Web Applications", title: ""},
  {name: "Mobile App", title: ""},
  {name: "Software interface", title: ""},
  {name: "Utility software", title: ""},
  {name: "Entertainment and gaming applications", title: ""},
  {name: "Scripting language (Scripting)", title: ""},
  {name: "Plug-ins", title: ""},
  {name: "IT project management", title: ""},
  {name: "Internet telephony (VoIP)", title: ""},
  {name: "Information systems architecture", title: ""},
  {name: "Management information system (MIS)", title: ""},
  {name: "Information system provisioning", title: ""},
  {name: "Enterprise resource planning (ERP)", title: ""},
  {name: "Other - IT / Software", title: ""}
],
[
  {name: "Data mining / analysis", title: ""},
  {name: "CAD / CAM", title: ""},
  {name: "Manufacturing engineering", title: ""},
  {name: "Product development", title: ""},
  {name: "Industrial engineering", title: ""},
  {name: "Chemical engineering", title: ""},
  {name: "Materials engineering", title: ""},
  {name: "Electronics engineering", title: ""},
  {name: "Mechanical engineering", title: ""},
  {name: "Biological engineering", title: ""},
  {name: "Mathematical statistics", title: ""},
  {name: "Quality control analysis", title: ""},
  {name: "Design engineering", title: ""},
  {name: "Engineering project management", title: ""},
  {name: "Mathematics", title: ""},
  {name: "Physics", title: ""},
  {name: "Chemistry", title: ""},
  {name: "Other - Engineering / Science", title: ""}
],
[
  {name: "Graphics", title: ""},
  {name: "Logo、 Corporate identity system", title: ""},
  {name: "Visual design", title: ""},
  {name: "Drawing", title: ""},
  {name: "Printing design", title: ""},
  {name: "Photography", title: ""},
  {name: "Computer-aided design", title: ""},
  {name: "3D Design", title: ""},
  {name: "Audio effects", title: ""},
  {name: "Video / Movie", title: ""},
  {name: "Dubbing", title: ""},
  {name: "Animation", title: ""},
  {name: "Framework design", title: ""},
  {name: "Website design", title: ""},
  {name: "User interface design", title: ""},
  {name: "Fashion design", title: ""},
  {name: "Industrial esign", title: ""},
  {name: "Other - Design / Creativity", title: ""}
],
[
  {name: "Promotions", title: ""},
  {name: "E-mail and internet marketing", title: ""},
  {name: "Telemarketing", title: ""},
  {name: "Search engine optimization and marketing", title: ""},
  {name: "Social media marketing", title: ""},
  {name: "Customer / Media relations", title: ""},
  {name: "Business planning / strategy", title: ""},
  {name: "Market research", title: ""},
  {name: "Sales", title: ""},
  {name: "Other - Business / Marketing", title: ""}
],
[
  {name: "Typing and data entry", title: ""},
  {name: "IT assistant", title: ""},
  {name: "Sales assistant", title: ""},
  {name: "Accounting assistant", title: ""},
  {name: "Business correspondence", title: ""},
  {name: "Transcription", title: ""},
  {name: "On-line customer services", title: ""},
  {name: "Field support / On-site services", title: ""},
  {name: "Quotation / Order processing", title: ""},
  {name: "Inventory processing", title: ""},
  {name: "Other - General affairs / Customer services", title: ""}
],
[
  {name: "General accounting", title: ""},
  {name: "Computer billing system", title: ""},
  {name: "Salary", title: ""},
  {name: "Financial services", title: ""},
  {name: "Financial planning and forecasting", title: ""},
  {name: "Financial statements", title: ""},
  {name: "Procurement process", title: ""},
  {name: "Legal", title: ""},
  {name: "Intellectual property protection", title: ""},
  {name: "Project management", title: ""},
  {name: "Human resources", title: ""},
  {name: "Recruitment", title: ""},
  {name: "Actuary", title: ""},
  {name: "Other - Business services", title: ""}
],
[
{name: "Blog writing", title: ""},
{name: "Ghostwriting", title: ""},
{name: "Tweets writing", title: ""},
{name: "Creative writing", title: ""},
{name: "Editorial", title: ""},
{name: "On-line journalist", title: ""},
{name: "Technical writing", title: ""},
{name: "Literature review", title: ""},
{name: "Translation、interpretation、verbatim", title: ""},
{name: "Other - Writing / Translation", title: ""}
],
[
  {name: "Legal adviser", title: ""},
  {name: "Travel consultant", title: ""},
  {name: "Immigration consultant", title: ""},
  {name: "Technical consultant", title: ""},
  {name: "Culinary consultant", title: ""},
  {name: "Language / Communication consultant", title: ""},
  {name: "Marketing consultant", title: ""},
  {name: "Overseas jobs consulting", title: ""},
  {name: "Business consultant", title: ""},
  {name: "Consultanting analysis", title: ""},
  {name: "Service advisor", title: ""},
  {name: "Other - Consultant", title: ""}
]
]
```

But I am not good at javascript...
please help me to let this done >"<

(the controller is like this)

```
def new
  @main_skill_id = params[:main].nil? ? -1 : params[:main].to_i
  @sub_skill_id = params[:sub].nil? ? -1 : params[:sub].to_i
  @project = Project.new
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect these skill categories, and sub skills, to be driven from the database, not a yaml file.  Then the selects would be passing through `skill_category_id` and `sub_skill_id`

When you come to do the selects, you have two strategies:  which one you choose depends on how many sub skills you are likely to have.

A) Render the main skill category, then render all of the sub skill selects, but make them all hidden with `style="display:none;"`.  Make sure each has an id which links them to an option in the main skill select.  Add an on change event to the main skill select to hide the currently shown sub skill select and show the one with the id matching the chosen option in the main skill select.

B) Ajax.  If you have lots of skills and lots of sub skills (eg thousands), rendering out a select for each could end up making your page slow to load.  So, just render out the main skill select, and make an empty div to hold the sub skill select.  When the main skill select changes, make an ajax call to a url like "/skill_categories/refresh_sub_skill_select?id=123".  This action should replace the contents of the empty sub skill div with a partial, which in turn just renders out the sub skill select for a given main skill (got from params[:id]).

Comment: +1 on having the categories driven from the database